# how to resolve SUP server time out error?

Tags: ios, sybase, sup

While connecting to sup server from ios code i am getting this error 
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'SUPApplicationTimeoutException', reason: 'registration took longer then @i'"
please some one help me out on this.

Comment: I have got the solution for this problem.
Previously i was trying to connect through relay server(Farm ID:xxx) but now i have changed the relay server address as 0(Farm ID:0) and now its successfully connect and register to sup server.

Comment: You avoided the error, not managed it :)
If your app starts without internet connection, or if the server is not reachable/not responds in time, you'll face the crash once again. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to connect through relay server in sup side because of that i was getting time out error. Later i tried to connect directly to the SUP, now its connect to sup server and register the device.

```
 SUP server side required details are
    SUPServerName:xxx
    SUPServerPort:xxx
    SUPUserName:xxx
    SUPFarmID:0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the Timeout (or a generic NSException) when initializing the SUP client to avoid the crash (allowing you to manage the network error)

```
        @try
        {
            [app registerApplication:SUP_TIMEOUT];
        }
        @
        catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            MBOLogError(@"%@: %@", [exception name], [exception reason]);
        }
```